# Need php to load files from folders and subfolders, and then sort the results added to a array

Tags: php, sorting, directory

I need to search into folders and subfolders in search for files. In this search I need to know the files names and their path, because I have different folders and files inside of those.

I have this name 05-Navy, and inside this folder I have 3 files called 05_Navy_White_BaseColor.jpg, 05_Navy_White_Normal.jpg and 05_Navy_White_OcclusionRoughnessMetallic.jpg.

I need to only get one of them at a time because I need to add they separately to different lists.

Then I came up with the code below:

```
   function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()) {
            $files = scandir($dir);

            $findme = '_BaseColor';

            $mypathCordas = null;
            $findmeCordas = 'Cordas';
        
            foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);

                $mypathCordas = $path;
                $pos = strpos($mypathCordas, $findme);
                $posCordas = strpos($mypathCordas, $findmeCordas);
                
                if (!is_dir($path)) {
                    if($posCordas == true){
                        if($pos == true){
                            $results[] = $path;
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else if ($value != "." && $value != ".." ) {
                    if($posCordas == true){
                        echo "</br>";
                            getDirContents($path, $results);
                            //$results[] = $path;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            sort( $results );
            for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){
                echo $results[$i];
                
                echo "</br>";
            }
            return $results;
        }
        
        getDirContents('scenes/Texturas');
```

as output result I get this: Results[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyvQG.png)

Which is not ideal at all, the biggest problem is that the list inserts the same values every time it has do add new ones, and as you can see, it doesn't sort one bit, but it shuffles. I did other things, like I have tried to use DirectoryIterator which worked really well, but I couldn't sort at all...

The printing each time something new is on the list might be my for(), but I am relatively new to php, so I can't be sure.

Also, there's this thing where it gets all the path, and I already tried using other methods but got only errors, where I would only need the scenes/texturas/ instead of the absolute path....

Comment: You are trying all file names in all your subfolders with their full path? I think, sort is an another problem?

Comment: You will need recursion (as you try), or if iterative you will need a "stack". If recursion is not your thing, then this can be done iteratively with a forever growing "stack" for each new sub dir. By "stack" i just mean a simple array of strings holding the path of each encountered folder. Which you would traverse in your loop.

Comment: And how Would I do that? @GetSet

Comment: @oguzhancerit well, I could use just their names and father folder, and use a variable to concatenate with those...

Comment: I guess you could if you already will assume sub folders are only 1 level nested deep.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Yes, get all deepest file names and their parent folder. Concat with your variable.

Comment: @oguzhancerit either way, the problem would be the same described... No sort neither better array introduction...

Comment: Do you got any documentation that you can provide me, or examples? @GetSet

Comment: The technical term is "graph traversal" @MarcosPaulo. So if you wanted to look further on algorithms and such, that would be your keyword for internet search

Comment: thats waaaaay beoynd scope @GetSet I just need a simples a dirt solution, go to the subfolders, find the thing that matches the name, add it path to the array, rinse and repeat 'till there's no subfolder. Then sort the array, or just read the folders in the order they are, instead of going first, second, third, thirteenth, fourteenth, fourth,.........

Comment: On your last comment, you just described the solution *iteratively* actually, and you described it *very* well. But SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: But even if "off topic" even though we are in the domain of "graph traversals", so not really. You could add keywords for "iterative". You could even just internet search for how to grab a "directory tree". All im saying to you is some research.

Comment: I am really glad that you are helping me, but I am not asking the code done, I am asking simpler solutions, I have 32 open pages in my browser in search for that. But again, thank you, I will try other stuff.